# How to post parameters to the server using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift4.1

I don't know if I am posting the parameters correctly?

```
func removeCart(rowId: Int, completion: @escaping (Bool)->()) {
    let urlString = "\(BaseUrl.Protina.rawValue)/ApiShoppingCart/UpdateCart"
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/form-data"]
    let parameters : [String: Any] = ["removefromcart": rowId]

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            let jsonData = JSON(data)
            print(jsonData)
            completion(true)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

when a user tries to remove an item from the cart, the above function gets fired
and after item deleted the rest of the items from cart will return.

Also, I tested it with `postman` and it was successful.

Comment: Do you want to parse `data`?

Comment: i want to pass the parameter in the function

Comment: @kavehnaseri, What error you are facing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the problem was in the parameter and encoding.

Changed it to this:

```
let parameters: [String:Any]= [
    "removefromcart": rowId,
    "Content-Type" : "application/form-data"
]
```

And the encoding should be `URLEncoding.httpBody`